# LINQ Select Modified Version From Datatable

Tags: linq, datatable, dataview

Can you please provide me with a sample syntax for it?

Something like this?

```
var qry = (ds.table.Select(s => s.col, string.Empty, DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent));
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669099.aspx) on querying the DataRowView.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));

table.Rows.Add(1);
table.Rows.Add(2);
table.Rows.Add(3);
table.AcceptChanges();
DataView view = new DataView(table);

table.Rows[1][0] = -2;
table.Rows[2][0] = -3;

view.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;

var query = from DataRowView rowView in view
            select rowView;
```

Comment: thank you thedugas but your first answer did'nt help. sorry if my question is misleading but this code worked for me.

var query = (table.Select("TRUE", string.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).Select(s => new { col = s.Field<string>("col") }));